# How to fetch all elements from HTML code having h2 element in python selenium package?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

[website : https://www.covid19india.org/state/MH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2wzt.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2wzt.png)

I want to fetch all district wise total cases and daily cases by tag h2 or h5 as per html code. I tried By.CLASS_NAME,BY.TAG_NAME but not getting elements.

I used below 2 lines to get district data
state = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "State")
districts = state.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "district")

and using for loop for getting cases data:

```
 for district in districts:
        # tag_district = district.find_element(By.XPATH, "h5")
        # tag_district = district.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "//h5")
        # tag_district = district.find_elements_by_tag_name('h5')
        # district_name = tag_district.text
        # print(tag_district)
```

nothing works.

which is useless as I want to export as csv.

Comment: Would you please tell why did you put two forward slashes while passing tag-name parameter & no slashes in xpath string parameter (2nd & 3rd lines in your code snippet) ? I suggest you to retry by removing the 2 slashes from tag-name parameter & attach two forward slashes to your xpath string parameter.

Comment: Make sure "districts" webelement list contains correct element first print them and validate

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "nothing works"?

Comment: Issue resolved. `state = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "state-right")`                            
`districts = state.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "district") and then running for loop over districts and fetching details as `district.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h5")`. This way I am getting daily active case district wise.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark- nothing works meant I was not able to get district names and daily covid cases count. I wanted to use h5 tag, Above code worked for me in pycharm using selenium

Comment: @AmitJain- Yes. I did mistake in it. district web driver elements were wrong. whole district data is under state right class so used state right and then traversed over district. Refer above code

Comment: @Rahul -  Yes.. You  were right, I removed // in h5 tag but also fetched state-right class first instead of state class to get exact parent.